# Prolog Undefined procedure (DWIM could not reach goal)

Tags: prolog, transitive-closure

I always get the erro mentioned above when I try this code

```
reicher(adam,berta).
reicher(berta,clemens).
reicher(adam,erwin).
reicher(eva,adam).

% adam > berta & erwin & clemens
% berta > clemens
& eva > all

reicher_als (X, Y):- reicher(X,Y).
reicher_als (X, Y):- reicher(X,Z),reicher_als(Z,Y).
```

For example I ask prolog `?- reicher_als(eva,clemens)` it gives me the error.

Comment: The code above contains syntax errors: There are superfluous spaces: `als (` should read `als(`. So you got some error message during compilation...

Comment: And there is a `&` which should read `%`

Comment: wow.... the spaces. That was a dumb one, thank you